# Detail in the proof of the Seifert-van Kampen theorem.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In the  proof of the Seifert van Kampen theorem there is a detail which I don't understand. It is formulated as a lemma in the book that I am using (Algebraische Topologie - Zieschang, Stöcker (German)).

The setup: Consider the inclusions and the by these inclusions induced homomorphisms, as in the attached picture. $X$ is a topological space s.t $X = U \cup V$ and $U, V \subset X$ and $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

The Lemma says the following: If $w: I \to U \cap V$ is a closed loop with Basepoint $x_0$, then $[w]_U \cdot N = [w]_V \cdot N$.

Here $N$ is the normal subgroup of $G$ that is gegnerated by $i'_\ast([w]_{U \cap V}) \cdot j'_\ast([w]_{U \cap V})^{-1}$, with $[w]_{U \cap V} \in \pi_1(U \cap V, x_0)$, where $G$ is the free product $\pi_1(U,x_0) \ast \pi_1(V,x_0)$.

The Lemma is left without proof. However, the reasoning seems to rely upon the fact that if $w: I \to U \cap V$ is indeed a closed loop as in the Lemma, then $i'_\ast([w]_{U \cap V}) = [w]_U$ and $j'_\ast([w]_{U \cap V}) = [w]_V$. I cannot figure out how to get from this point to the conclusion of the lemma. I would be grateful for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the subgroup $N$ is normal, notice that it also contains the elements $j'_*([w]_{U\cap V})^{-1} \cdot i'_*([w]_{U\cap V})$, which are conjugates of the generators.

Then, starting from $i'_*([w]_{U\cap V}) = [w]_{U}$ and $j'_*([w]_{U\cap V}) = [w]_{V}$, let us compute $[w]_{V}^{-1} \cdot [w]_{U}$ in the free product $G = \pi_1(U,x_0) \ast \pi_1(V,x_0)$. We get
$$
 [w]_{V}^{-1} [w]_{U} = j'_*([w]_{U\cap V})^{-1} \cdot i'_*([w]_{U\cap V}) \in N
$$
hence
$$
 [w]_{V} \cdot N = [w]_{V} \cdot [w]_{V}^{-1} \cdot [w]_{U} \cdot N = [w]_{U} \cdot N \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. The first part of your comment i understand. What i do not understand is the following step:

$[w]_V \cdot N = [w]_V \cdot [w]^{-1}_V \cdot [w]_U \cdot N$

Is this a property of normal subgroups?

Comment: This is because $n \cdot N = N$ for every élément $n \in N$.

Comment: ah ok, thank you very much.